# How can I sort strings in a list based on common characters using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I want to compare a list of strings and if a certain sequence of characters match, I want to put those matching strings into a `new_list`, like so:

```
string_list1 = ['CE.1.FXZ', 'CE.1.FXX', 'CE.1.FXY', 'CE.4.FXZ', 'CE.4.FXX', 'CE.4.FXY']

new_list = ['CE.1.FXZ', 'CE.1.FXX', 'CE.1.FXY']
```

As you can see, the common character in each is either `1` or `4`.

My question is how can I separate strings based on a common character, if I do not know the common character beforehand? For example, I would like to parse the `string_list1` into a function and have the function automatically identify the common characters and then separate based on that. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: I would not call `1` and `4` as the only common chars - `F` char also could easily be treated as a common char. What you intend looks more as determining the distinguishing chars

Comment: Can you give any additional restrictions? E.g., if you only want to have two sets?

Comment: @SimonFink Essentially I want as many lists as there are common characters

Comment: I don't know what's meant by "common" or "matching" characters.  `C` and `E` are common characters.  Each string starts with `CE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate the "common character" in your example with python built-in str.split() method (more info at https://docs.python.org/fr/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) like so :

```
for i in string_list1:
    common_character = i.split(".")[1]
```

Next step would be creating a list each time you see a novel "common_character" or adding your element to an existing list using the list.append() method (one by one).

Best of luck !

Answer (score 0):

If the common char is always the second token (when split on the `.`) you can use a default dict where each key is the common char and each value is the list of common chars.

```
from collections import defaultdict

string_list1 = ['CE.1.FXZ', 'CE.1.FXX', 'CE.1.FXY', 'CE.4.FXZ', 'CE.4.FXX', 'CE.4.FXY']

common_chars = defaultdict(list)
for str in string_list1:
    common_chars[str.split('.')[1]].append(str)
for common_group in common_chars.values():
    print(common_group)
```

Outputs:

```
['CE.1.FXZ', 'CE.1.FXX', 'CE.1.FXY']
['CE.4.FXZ', 'CE.4.FXX', 'CE.4.FXY']
```